Polyline from coordinates array in OL v9.2.2
I'm trying to implement something like this example in Angular 17. I can't replicate this part:
const polyline = result.routes[0].geometry;

const route = new Polyline({
  factor: 1e6,
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
});

Since I have my data in a Coordinate[].
How can I do this? I failed to find the proper type on the library. Polyline seems not to have the properties shown in the example above.
I tried a few things like this:
const polyline = OpenLayersService.cordinatesToGeoJSONLineString(trip);

    const route = new Polyline({
      factor: 1e6,
    }).readGeometry(polyline, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });
    console.log(`ROUTE`, route);

    const routeFeature = new Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route,
    });

The final route don't have any properties shown in the example. My last approach ended up using my Coordinate[], but the marker just jumps between places instead of following the route when I animated it (Fitting, mostly because the moveFeature just go through the array one cord at the time.).
Features of route in the docs:
    const routeFeature = new Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route,
    });
    const startMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'icon',
      geometry: new Point(route.getFirstCoordinate()),
    });
    const endMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'icon',
      geometry: new Point(route.getLastCoordinate()),
    });
    const position = startMarker.getGeometry().clone();
    const geoMarker = new Feature({
      type: 'geoMarker',
      geometry: position,
    });

My route is just a Geometry.
Here is my array. It's just a Coordinate[].
[
    [
        -6458433.027427015,
        -4240406.793806622
    ],
    [
        -6458409.427694967,
        -4240625.878474302
    ],
    [
        -6458389.390186625,
        -4240901.074723888
    ],
    [
        -6458389.390186625,
        -4240901.074723888
    ],
    [
        -6458353.322671607,
        -4241147.676136185
    ],
    [
        -6458324.602242982,
        -4241346.795085759
    ],
    [
        -6458302.115705842,
        -4241507.735105882
    ],
    [
        -6458274.619791617,
        -4241694.132877366
    ],
    [
        -6458247.0125579,
        -4241881.628693057
    ],
    [
        -6458214.507266588,
        -4242101.153416152
    ],
    [
        -6458168.087038928,
        -4242265.526114608
    ],
    [
        -6458168.087038928,
        -4242265.526114608
    ],
    [
        -6458082.037072545,
        -4242252.387157167
    ],
    [
        -6457978.732585088,
        -4242228.162245663
    ],
    [
        -6457978.732585088,
        -4242228.162245663
    ],
    [
        -6457978.732585088,
        -4242228.162245663
    ],
    [
        -6457978.732585088,
        -4242228.162245663
    ],
    [
        -6457978.732585088,
        -4242228.162245663
    ]
]

I can draw it perfectly, as in this picture.

I can post the service, but it's a bit big at the time since I make it modular and multipurpose.

It's not clear of what missing properties are you talking/asking about. Please edit your question with more info about that.

I'm happy with an example with a different source in the polyline. I saw the strange polystring in the console, but I got my Cordinate[] directly from the DB, technically speaking I just transform it before using it on the service, though.

Sorry, but I still don't understand what/where your problem is. Can you post a sample from your coordinates?

Since your input is an array of Web Mercator EPSG:3857 coordinates, you can use LineString method to create route geometry.
Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:
const routeCoords = [
  [
    -6458433.027427015,
    -4240406.793806622
  ],
  [
    -6458409.427694967,
    -4240625.878474302
  ],
  [
    -6458389.390186625,
    -4240901.074723888
  ],
  .
  .
  .
];

const route = new LineString(routeCoords);

const routeFeature = new Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route
});


I'll give it a try. Can i use the same method in the example to go through the LineString?

What do you mean by "the same method"? All the rest stays the same, just geometry is created differently.

I mean the part you move the geoMarker with the moveFeature function. It worked like a charm, thank you for the answer. I assumed that I needed a Polyline, but you can use a LineString to do it.

Have a look at the polyline source from cited example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/polyline/route.json, and you'll see it's something completely different than array of coordinates for linestrting. Polyline is used  for reading and writing data in the Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_Polyline-Polyline.html.

I tried to convert my data in Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format with strange results, that's why I came asking here.
